# How to write shortcut for this code on delete

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to write shortcut for this code

for example , i'm going to delete many entries if it have certain words from db `my_table` `{id,my_words}`

```
$sql= "delete from my_table where my_words like '%some1%' or my_words like '%some2%'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed: $sql".mysql_error());
```

and i've many like some3 , some4 , some5 ..etc so i can't repeat `or my_words like '%some2%'`

many times otherwise it would be hard and the code is so long.
so how can i write shortcut like using arrays or something !

Thanks for help

Comment: are you trying to make the code re-usable? Just wrap it in an object, or a function that you can call time and time again. Make it generic enough that you can just send an array or single string for deletion. Don't mix regex with SQL, leads to security issues if you don't handle it correctly.

Comment: Also using of regex makes the query slow.

Comment: This feels like you are trying to solve a problem in a rather roundabout fashion.  What precisely is it you are trying to do with the above?  I'm guessing delete urls that have specific domains in them?  If so it may be worth storing domain separately at point of insertion i.e. a seperate field which would give you a specific field to select on.  Just a thought.

Comment: Okay, will not using regex thanks for the informations and the problem i'm trying to solve it to ban any spam cause i've been infected by some heavy spam bots that post chemical banned substance for selling so i might ban 90% of it by doing this ! till i find another way and i'm doing hard searching already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = array('your','words',...);

foreach($a as $k=>$value{
$sql= "delete from my_table where my_words like '%$value%'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed: $sql".mysql_error());
}
```

don't use OR in your sql statement this time, just loop, as you need to delete all - just do it for each word.

Comment: Can you explain why one would want to avoid using `DELETE [...] WHERE column = ? OR column = ?`? I don't see any problem doing this. On the other hand I see a performance issue with your suggestion.

Comment: @  Basti - because in this instance it's not necessary, and again as i understood Jack needed fast fix to his problem - not a long working solution...

Comment: @  Jack - welcome, but yes Basti is right - if you have thousands of words to run it for or on large database, you will probably need more optimised solution.

Comment: so it's just your quick solution and not a general rule of thumb? "don't use OR in sql, as you need to delete all - just do it for each word." kind of sounds like you are suggesting not to use `OR` in SQL at all.

Comment: it just 10 words and my db is small also my website with no more than 1k visitor / month and that words are name of banned drugs some spam bots doing their best to post it :) and it would be fast solution till i stop that bots by other ways.

Comment: @ Jack - in this case i wouldn't worry much about performance - even running it once a day =)